# Selection-change event in office word c#

Tags: c#, selection, office-interop

How can I make selection-change event in office word c#?

Office 2010
Visual Studio 2010
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havn't tested it, but you might want to check the event [ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_windowselectionchangeeventhandler%28v=office.11%29.aspx) . The events are in the delegate section.